# Scrape dynamic info from same URL using python or any other tool

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to **scrape** the URL of every company who has posted a job offer on this website:
https://jobs.workable.com/

I want to pull the info to generate some stats re this website.

The problem is that when I click on an add and navigate through the job post, the url is always the same. I know a bit of python so any solution using it would be useful. I am open to any other approach though.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you have any code, show it. If you're a python beginner it might be better to learn python and then build the skills required to solve this problem. It's very unlikely someone would write a complete solution from the ground up for you as you're asking.

Comment: I have no code because I have no idea on what would be the correct approach. I usually use beautifulsoup with the url I want to scrap but in this case there is no url that I can use.

I really just need to know the right direction to follow and then I'll do the code myself

Comment: you can navigate to XHR tab and check there. i get the link which has the result store as follows:-

https://job-board-v3.workable.com/api/v1/jobs?query=&orderBy=postingUpdateTime+desc
 after this you just need to parse it correctly to get the desired results

Comment: That's amazing, thank you so much. One last question: how can get the results for the rest of the pages? The link you shared includes only the first page results.

Comment: sure if you closely monitor the XHR while changing and going to next page you can observe a simple URL generation pattern. I will just share the pseudo-code below, so it might help others as well, you can generate the parsing logic and the depth or number of pages you want to scrape.

Comment: Great Prakhar, thanks a million. You really helped me a lot. Where did you share the pseudo code? For my own knowledge, where do you monitor the XHR in Mozilla?

Comment: Found it! Thanks a million!

Comment: happy to help :)
If you feel the issue is resolved, please accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left handside in my answer. and the XHR is found in Network tab usually i made a typo in above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a pseudo code to give you the idea of what you are looking for.

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

first_url = 'https://job-board-v3.workable.com/api/v1/jobs?query=&orderBy=postingUpdateTime+desc'
base_url= 'https://job-board-v3.workable.com/api/v1/jobs?query=&orderBy=postingUpdateTime+desc&offset='
page_ids = ['0','10','20','30','40','50'] ## can also be created dynamically this is just raw

for pep_id in page_ids:
    # for initial page
    if(pep_id ==  '0'):
        page = requests.get(first_url, headers=headers)
        print('You still need to parse the first page')
        ##Enter some parsing logic
    else:
        final_url = base_url + str(pep_id)
        page = requests.get(final_url, headers=headers)
        print('You still need to parse the other pages')
        ##Enter some parsing logic
```